# Docker Build Error

Tags: docker

I am creating my own docker image :

```
RUN apt-get install git python-dev python-pip
RUN pip install pyCrypto ecdsa paramiko
RUN git clone https://github.com/bendacoder/pyTerminal
RUN cd pyTerminal
RUN python -m py_compile terminal.py
```

However when I build the code, I receive this error :

```
FATA[0000] The Dockerfile (Dockerfile) must be within the build context (Dockerfile)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the exact command you're using to build the image?

Comment: The command I was using is docker build -t pyTerminalBuild Dockerfile.

Answer (score -1):

You say you were using trying to build with the command:

```
docker build -t pyTerminalBuild Dockerfile
```

This is wrong.  `docker build`'s positional parameter must be a path to a directory (or a URL to a tarball or Git repo, or `-`), and Docker expects to find a file named `Dockerfile` (or something else specified with `-f`) in that directory.  The correct way to build an image from a Dockerfile in the current directory is thus:

```
docker build -t pyTerminalBuild .
```

Comment: The command did not work. Instead it gave me another error : FATA[0000] Error checking context is accessible: 'can't stat '.''. Please check permissions and try again.

Comment: Among other things, your RUN cd ... followed By another  RUN will fail, because it is the same as do `cd abc` in a terminal and in another terminal, launch some code requiring to be in that directory, when you are not. You should replace your last 2 RUN by `RUN cd xxx ; python -m ... `